# How to avoid commiting minified react files to source code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, package.json

I have 2 different react projects, let say projectA , projectB

here i am using projectA build files(minified files, the files which i got after doing npm build) in the projectB **public** folder

the process which i am doing is manually copying build files into public folder and using those files inside projectB, but the problem  here is i had to  commit the minified files into repository which i should not be doing it ,

is there any way that i can copy or specify the path of projectA dependencies when i build or run the projectB ?

my whole point is to avoid committing minified files to source code

Comment: Add `public` folder to `.gitignore`

Comment: but i need to use public folder inside projectB, is there any way that i can specify copy command script in package.json something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can specify copy command script in `package.json`. You can run any bash command in scripts

Comment: it would be helpful if you could give any reference

Comment: Something like: `"build": "react-scripts build && cp -r dist ../projectB/public"`